# casting of an address

Tags: c, casting

You have an operating system, which has 2 functions dealing with memory allocation:

```
void *malloc( int sz ) // allocates a memory block sz bytes long

void free( void *addr ) // frees a memory block starting at addr
                        //  (previously allocated by malloc)
```

Using these functions, implement the following 2 functions:

```
void *malloc_aligned( int sz ) // allocates a memory block sz bytes long,
                               //  aligned to an address divisible by 16

void free_aligned( void *addr )  // frees a memory block starting at addr
                                 // (previously allocated by malloc_aligned)
```

in the solution there is the following part:

```
void * aligned_malloc(size_t size){
     unsigned char *res=malloc(size+16);
     unsigned char offest=16-((long)res%16);
```

What I don't understand is: Why do we need to use unsigned char and why and what we achieve using `16-((long)res%16);` and what is the purpose of `(long)res` in this case?

Comment: is it the known question from Jango?!

Comment: yes this is the question from jungo

Comment: A. Good luck than (: B. the answer here below is good.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not going to the interview :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do pointer arithmetic on "void *", because void has no size.
When adding to a pointer or subtracting to it, it's always done in units of `sizeof(*p)`. Meaning - if you add one to an int pointer, its value grows by 4 (because the size of an integer is 4). So when you add to a void pointer, it should grow by the size of a void. But void has no size.

However, some compilers are willing to do arithmetic on `void *`, and they treat it like `char *`. With these compilers, you could implement these functions without casting. But it isn't standard.

Another point is that not all operators are applicable for pointers. Addition and subtraction are, but multiplication, division and modulus are not. So if you want to test the low bits of a pointer, to know if it's aligned, you cast it to a long.
Why long? The assumption is that long is as large as a pointer, which is true in Linux, but not in Windows. The right type is uintptr_t. However, if you're only interested in the low bits, it doesn't matter if you lose the high bits while casting. So a cast to int would have worked too.

Comment: ok this explains the unsigned char but how do I explain the long(res)?

Comment: Indeed, I only answered half the question. Edited my answer to add the rest.

Comment: few things I don't understand is: a. what does it mean to test the low bits of a pointer. b. what does it mean that bits are aligned?